# What is the significance of the abstract painting?

Tags: alfred-hitchcock, suspicion

In Alfred Hitchcock's Suspicion, we observe a detective staring at a painting when visiting the home of Lena and Johnnie:
[image: abstract-painting-suspicion]

Both upon the entrance and exit of the detectives, he is entranced by the painting. Furthermore, both times he must be snapped out of this trance by the other detective.

*What is the significance of the painting?*

Answer (score 5):

The detective is trying to make sense of the picture, as detectives are tasked with trying to make sense of things in any given case.

The picture could also be seen as a representation of Lina's [frazzled state of mind](http://theartofilm.blogspot.com/2013_07_01_archive.html).